# Bootstrap navbar always collapsed for Drupal theme

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drupal, stylesheet

I'm attempting to upgrade [Open Framework theme](https://github.com/SU-SWS/open_framework) for Drupal from Bootstrap 2.3.1 to Bootstrap 3.1.1.  I've already made most of the simple conversions from span* to col-md-*, changed row-fluid to row, etc...

However, I'm a bit stumped as to why the navbar is constantly in a collapsed state. Where did I go wrong? The [entire project is forked at GitHub](https://github.com/BlueScot/opened_framework).

This is the relevant section of page.tpl.php

```
<div id="main-menu" class="clearfix site-main-menu">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
      <?php if ($main_menu): ?>

      <div class="container">
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($page['search_box']): ?>
        <div id="nav-search" class="nav-search"> <?php print render($page['search_box']); ?> </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($main_menu): ?>
        <button class="btn btn-navbar collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
        <?php if ($primary_nav || !empty($page['navigation'])): ?>
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
          <nav id="main-nav" role="navigation">
            <?php if (($primary_nav) && empty($page['navigation'])): ?>
            <?php print render($primary_nav); ?> 
            <!-- /#primary-menu -->
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if (!empty($page['navigation'])): ?>
            <?php print render($page['navigation']); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($main_menu): ?>
      </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue here was converting all the div classes and elements over to the new Bootstrap 3.1.1 classes and forgoing the old classes. The reason the item always appeared collapsed was because the collapsed elements and the collapsed button were using the old styles.

Changing the button to the new style hid the button and created the default Bootstrap 3.1.1 header, leaving only the cell-phone style buttons. This was propagated to the Primary Nav section, which, when using render, created those buttons. Updating that to theme allowed the buttons to be printed Bootstrap 3.1.1 style as well. The changes are available on the GitHub project for examination, and the segment of code has been reproduced below (though still need to update the page-navigation portion).

```
<div id="header" class="clearfix header" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="<?php if ($page['search_box']): print 'col-md-8'; else: print 'col-md-12'; endif; ?>">
        <?php if ($logo): ?>
          <div id="logo" class="site-logo"> <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home"> <img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print $site_name; ?>" role="presentation" /> </a></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- /#logo -->
        <?php if ($site_name || $site_slogan): ?>
        <div id="name-and-slogan">
          <?php if ($site_name): ?>
          <div id="site-name" class="site-name"><a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home"><?php print $site_name; ?></a></div>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <?php if ($site_slogan): ?>
            <div id="site-slogan" class="site-slogan"><?php print $site_slogan; ?></div>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (!($site_name || $site_slogan)): ?>
          <div id="site" class="hide">
            <div id="name"><a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>"><?php print $my_site_title; ?></a></div>
          </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- /#name-and-slogan -->
        <?php if ($page['header']): ?>
          <div id="header-content" class="row header-content"><?php print render($page['header']); ?></div>
          <!-- /#header-content -->
        <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```